MongoDB query on Spring data and PropertyReferenceException
Our app uses Spring boot 3.3.6 and have the following scenario:
Model:
@Document(collection = "STORAGE_CLASS")
public class StorageClass {

    @Field("STATUS")
    private String status;

    @Field("FIELD_NUMBER")
    private long numberField;

    ... // getters, setters, tostring
}

We need to query this collection on database every 10 seconds, so we wrote a dao for it:
public interface StorageClassDao {
    List<StorageClass> getStorage();
}
@Repository
public class StorageClassDaoImpl implements StorageClassDao {
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    public StorageClassDaoImpl(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public List<StorageClass> getStorage() {
        Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("STATUS").is("E")
            .and("FIELD_NUMBER").is(1);
        Query query = new Query(criteria);
        return this.mongoTemplate.find(query, StorageClass.class);
    }
}

This works, I receive data from getStorage which matches the query I passed. However I see a lot of PropertyReferenceException are being thrown (If I add a breakpoint to this exception), with the messages as follows:
No property 'STATUS' found for type 'StorageClass'
No property 'STATU' found for type 'StorageClass'
No property 'STAT' found for type 'StorageClass'
No property 'STA' found for type 'StorageClass'
No property 'ST' found for type 'StorageClass'
No property 's' found for type 'StorageClass'
No property 'FIELD' found for type 'StorageClass'
No property 'FIEL' found for type 'StorageClass'
No property 'FIE' found for type 'StorageClass'
No property 'FI' found for type 'StorageClass'
No property 'f' found for type 'StorageClass'
No property 'FIELD_NUMBER' found for type 'StorageClass'
No property 'FIELD_NUMBE' found for type 'StorageClass'
No property 'FIELD_NUMB' found for type 'StorageClass
No property 'FIELD_NUM' found for type 'StorageClass'
No property 'FIELD_NU' found for type 'StorageClass'
No property 'FIELD_N' found for type 'StorageClass''
No property 'FIELD_' found for type 'StorageClass'

The exceptions are throwed manly from two places:
Exception 'org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException' occurred in thread 'scheduling-1' at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:490)
Exception 'org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException' occurred in thread 'scheduling-1' at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94)

For every service call, more than 100 of this exceptions are being throwed.
What am I doing wrong here?
Code for reference: https://github.com/felipeissa/mongo-db-exception
Spring boot version: 3.3.6
Spring data mongodb version: 4.3.6
Java version: 21

The issue is with how you have named mongoDB fields STATUS, FIELD_NUMBER and how you are trying to use them . Correct way to use them is by using java variable names status , numberField :
Updated Code :
@Override
public List<StorageClass> getStorage() {
    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("status").is("E")  
        .and("numberField").is(1);                       
    Query query = new Query(criteria);
    return this.mongoTemplate.find(query, StorageClass.class);
}


According to the criteria documentation, it can be either the property name (which you are suggesting) or the field name (which I'm using). Its not incorrect to use the field name, as it correctly search the entity with the filters I passed. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html#where(java.lang.String)
